# How do I count from 2 lists at the same time to return me a %?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a function that is supposed to return the number of males, and females hospitalized. I have the function working except this part.

```
'''
each of genders and ever hospitalized directly correlate to each other,
so, Female and Yes, Male and No, and so on. 

'''

ever_hospitalized = ['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No']   



print( count_gender(genders) )
```

So the question is, How do I make my current function return the percent of male and female cases hospitalized?

Desired output:

```
Female: 5 cases 71.43%
Male: 2 cases 28.57%
50.31% of females have been hospitalized
40.53% of males have been hospitalized
```

And I tried just dividing the values in my function to give the percentage, but it was taking all of them and dividing giving me an answer of `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67139935/14867730) logic is sufficient to answer you problem but here I am just for the sake of **OUTPUT** pattern requirement, add these line after `first loop iteration`.

```
...
    hos_mal_fem = {'Female':0, 'Male': 0}
    for i,j in enumerate(ever_hospitalized):
        if j == 'Yes':
            hos_mal_fem[genders[i]]+=1

    for i in hos_mal_fem:
        string += f"{hos_mal_fem[i]/genders.count(i)*100:.2f}% {i.lowers()}s have been hospitalized\n"
    return string
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary that holds all the totals for each gender. Then calculate the percentages from this.

Use `zip()` to iterate over both lists together.

```
def count_gender(genders, ever_hospitalized):
    gender_stats = {
        "Male": {"count": 0, "hospitalized": 0},
        "Female": {"count": 0, "hospitalized": 0}
    }
    for gender, hospitalized in zip(genders, ever_hospitalized):
        gender_stats[gender]["count"] += 1
        if hospitalized == "Yes":
            gender_stats[gender]["hospitalized"] += 1
    string = ''
    for type, stats in gender_stats.items():
        string += f"{type}: {stats['count']} cases {100*stats['count']/len(genders):.2f}%\n"
        string += f"{100*stats['hospitalized']/stats['count']:.2f}% have been hospitalized\n"
    return string
```

Comment: The 2 functions I provided already count the genders, is there a way you can just add a couple of lines to the provided function? Thank you.

Comment: @James It needs the `zip` loop to count the hospitalizations, so it's simpler to just count the genders in the same loop.